# Setting up default web parts on a Wiki Page from a Web Template in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

My team is trying to build out a Web Template which includes an instantiated Wiki Page with some default Web Parts added to it; but we're unable to get this behavior to happen.

In brief, we're looking to add some default.aspx (or Home.aspx, the name is unimportant, just the functionality) to the SitePages directory, GhostableInLibrary; so it's visible to all SiteCollections made from this Web Template.

It is of note that we're basing our Web Collection off the Team Site, and that the Wiki will be the default Home Page for the new site.

Comment: Can you tell us the problem you are facing, Is it a site definition or site template ?

Comment: If this was SharePoint 2007, we would have used Site Definitions. Since the new recommendation is to use custom web templates, that's what we're trying to do. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff408263.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Site templates can be used to customize newly created sites except for the top site of a site collection. Since site templates are all managed in site collection's Solution gallary, so a site template CAN'T be used to define its own container.
You need a Site Definition to customize the first site of your site collection.

For how to use site template, you can goto, http://weblogs.asp.net/soever/archive/2009/10/19/sharepoint-2010-site-exporting-as-wsp-solution-part-1.aspx

For how to create a site definition, you can goto, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg276356.aspx

Comment: You can define custom web templates and create top level sites from them, which is what we're trying to do: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff408263.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to strap onto an existing template without creating a new copy, or you don't have the original site template to access. You use a process called feature stapling.

When you create a sharepoint solution it would contain two features, one for your actual functionality and one that simple staples it to an existing template.

Here is an article discussing it some more. http://mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1065

Comment: Are you suggesting that a customized default wiki page can be stapled on as a feature?

Comment: I'm suggesting a feature can be stapled to the existing site template so that when a new site is created with this template, the feature will execute automatically. This feature would be responsible for adding the web parts and pages you need.

Comment: We are aware that you can modify a page through code which runs as a feature. Is there a way to just include a customized wiki page as part of the web template?

Comment: yes, a sharepoint module is what is used to include files to a library. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms453137.aspx

and 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms441170.aspx

Comment: That would appear to be an avenue we haven't taken...we'll investigate this further.  Thank you, Brian.

Comment: We haven't been able to verify in time if this approach will work, but I'm going to give you the bounty.